# how to blur background when modal pop up in react native

Tags: react-native, modal-dialog

How to blur the background only when react native modal popup.my code
<View style={{styles.container }}>

```
 <SafeAreaView>
  <FlatList />
 </SafeAreaView>
 <Modal
  animationType={'fade'}
  transparent={true}
  onRequestClose={() => { this.setState({ ItemmodalVisible: false }); }}
  visible={this.state.ItemmodalVisible}
 />
</View
```

I want that when modal popup the `flatlist` should blur

Answer (score -1):

You can try using [react-native-blur](https://github.com/Kureev/react-native-blur) Following Usage

```
 <View style={styles.container}>
  <SafeAreaView>
   <FlatList />
   { this.state.ItemmodalVisible && <BlurView
      style={styles.absolute}
      blurType="light"
      blurAmount={10}
      reducedTransparencyFallbackColor="white"
    />}
  </SafeAreaView>
  <Modal
   ....
  />
</View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  absolute: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0
  }
});
```

Comment: it only increase opacity i also want to blur the view

Comment: Did you check the library? It does not only use opacity.